# Include SELECT statement result in IF statement

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-webpages, user-roles

I am working on a simple ASP.NET Intranet with Windows Authentication. I am authenticating users with Active Directory to allow them access to the site, but would like to implement site-specific user roles to manage page & content access without disturbing or adding to the Windows User Groups already in place.

My thought on how to accomplish this was to create a `UserRoles` table, and place a specific `RoleId` in the `Users` table for each user. Then I would compare the `Currently Logged In` username with the `Users` table to find out which role the user is in.

Question 1: 
   
Is this an OK way to go about this?

Question 2 (If the answer to question 1 is yes):

How can I select the correct RoleId for the current user, and use in an IF statement?

This is what I was thinking:

```
var db = Database.Open("Database") ;

// Find out what my Windows Username is
var currentUser = Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.Substring(Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1);

// Find out what Role I'm in    
var getUser = "SELECT RoleId FROM Users WHERE UserID = @0";

// Get the result
var selectedUser = db.Query(getUser, currentUser);

var requiredRole = "1";

// Choose where I should go
if (SelectedRoleId != requiredRole)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/AreaRestricted");
}
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET includes a very adaptive RoleManager. A while back, I created a custom method like the one you are using here and then I discovered the SqlRoleProvider and it was incredible. Does everything you need it to and you can implement it with or without SqlMembershipProvider.

Add this to system.web section of your web.config:

```
<!-- Configure the Sql Role Provider -->
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="SqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="QCmembership" applicationName="Quality_Training_2" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Then you can just add a new custom roles using the built-in commands, and add users to those roles in the same way. It just needs a string value of the username or some kind of identifier. Looks something like this:

```
Roles.AddUserToRole("anyUserName", "myCustomRole")
```

More information (including a list of the role provider's methods) can be found [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlroleprovider.aspx).

Comment: What goes in the web.config? Thanks.

Comment: @Jack So strange that I didn't see that code not uploaded. Give me a sec

Comment: @Jack There you go. It was actually there but I forgot to format it as code so Stack Overflow wasn't displaying it.

Comment: I apologize if I sound naive, but do I need to created tables in my database for this or are they created automatically?

Comment: @Jack I think they use the tables created by the SqlMembershipProvider, but check the link to be sure.

Comment: I will, I have just been too busy to test this.

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1:** No, that is not the right way to go about it. People *will* need multiple roles (whether you need them now or not). You should have something similar to:

```
Users Table (you already have this)

Roles Table
[id] INT
[description] VARCHAR(100)

UserRoles Table
[userId] INT --or whatever
[roleId] INT
```

**Question 2:** To manage roles, you'll need to implement a [Custom Role Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx). Which, boiled down is two steps:

1. Create a class that inherits the RoleProvider abstract class from the System.Web.Security namespace. This is where you'll have the functions to check if a user is in a role or not by overriding the [IsInRole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.isuserinrole.aspx) method. This is likely one of the few functions you'll need to override, for most purposes (like if you handle adding and deleting roles somewhere else, for example).
2. Tell the [web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms164660%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to use this new custom Role Provider.

[Sample Role-Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/317sza4k.ASPX)

Then you will be able to simply do an `If` on [User.IsInRole("roleName")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprincipal.isinrole.aspx) to see if someone is in a role, and the Role Provider takes care of rest.